# Why creating a process is a two-step process (fork-exec)?

Tags: unix, process, forking

I'm studying Tanenbaum's "Modern Operating Systems" book and he's explaining that:

> The reason for this two-step process is to allow the child to manipulate its file descriptors after the fork but before the execve to accomplish redirection of standard input, standard output, and standard error.

Could you further elaborate on that?

Comment: Does he mention CLOSE ON EXEC?  There are file descriptor attributes that dictate whether or not a file descriptor persists across an exec.  So if a descriptor will close you may need to do something with it, like call ioctl(), fcntl() to change attributes.

Comment: No I'm afraid he doesn't give more information about that.